# How to apply CSS to get the DDA.AC character wrapped in a tag to the center of the screen

Tags: html, css

I want to have the DDA.AC text in the middle when the web page gets smaller.

```
text-align: center; for any tag it does not change.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4oz0yuf7/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please define your question better (i.e. what's _smaller_?), along with a brief explanation of what you've tried.

Comment: use position to align your content.

Comment: how?? text-align: center; for any tag it does not change.

Comment: Please show your JS/CSS etc in this question itself. A link to a Fiddle is not sufficient, as that might change or be deleted over time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@media (max-width: 768px)` to set the css when the browser screen width is small. That's also the width when your hamburger menu appears.

You also need to extend `.container`'s width to the full width, and turn off the `float` for `.navbar-brand`. When the screen is larger than 768px, all these settings will *not* apply and will revert to your default.

You can try adding this to your css:

```
 @media (max-width: 768px) {

.container {
        width:100%;
    }

    a.navbar-brand {
        display:block;
        float:none;
    }
}
```

```css
.navbar-toggle{
    float: left;
    right: 40px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand{
    color: #f7ca02;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover{
    color: #f7ca02;
    opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-brand{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a{
    padding-left: 25px;
    transition: ease 0.5s;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-header{
    align-items: center;
}
.navbar-default {
    background-color: white;
    border-top:2px solid #f7960e;
    border-bottom-color: #77787a;
}
.navbar-fixed-top{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
a{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#card{
    color: #ef4721;
}
#login{
    left: 55px;
}
.container{
    margin-left: 19px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.jumbotron{

    background-image: url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/JXo_Zcavc5c4RIULtbyHrV7fShbnNr1-o0jsafXcOgwK_XApi-310FFg9IelshlQExI=w720-h310-rw');
    background-size: cover;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

.container {
        width:100%;
    }

    a.navbar-brand {
        display:block;
        float:none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ddaac.css">
 <title>DDA.AC</title>
</head>
<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DDA.AC</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">컨텐츠</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">덱리스트</a></li>
          <li><a id="card" href="#">카드평가</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">트위터</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">게시판</a></li>   
        </ul>
       
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a id="login" href="#">로그인</a></li>      
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid --> 
 </div>
 </nav>

 <div class="jumbotron">
  
 </div>


 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" ></script> 
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```